# How to iterate over a reference to the items in a Range and not the items themselves?

Tags: rust

Given a `Range`, is there a good way to iterate over the reference of the items rather than items themselves?  I'd like to write a function that takes an iterator to a structure that contains a number of unsigned integers.  Most of the time, the structure will be either a vector or a range.  In the case of a vector, the iterator gives a reference to the elements, which is the desired behavior.  In the case of a range, we get the integers themselves, which doesn't type check.  For example, consider the code:

```
// Take in an iterator and print it
fn foo<'a, T>(t: T)
where
    T: Iterator<Item = &'a usize>,
{
    for u in t {
        println!("{}", *u)
    }
}

// Run the function
fn main() {
    let x = vec![1, 3, 8];
    foo(x.iter());
    foo(x.iter());
    foo((1..4).collect::<Vec<usize>>().iter());
    //foo(1..4);
}
```

This code works fine and gives:

```
1
3
8
1
3
8
1
2
3
```

Note, it's important to our situation that `foo` does not consume `x`.  That said, the syntax for the range is cumbersome.  If we uncomment the above line, we get:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::ops::Range<{integer}> as Iterator>::Item == &usize`
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
5  | fn foo<'a, T>(t: T)
   |    --- required by a bound in this
6  | where
7  |     T: Iterator<Item = &'a usize>,
   |                 ---------------- required by this bound in `foo`
...
20 |     foo(1..4);
   |     ^^^ expected `&usize`, found integer
```

This makes sense.  The range converts to an iterator with the wrong type.  I'd like to fix that, or the routine, so that we can type either `foo(x.iter())` or `foo(1..4)` and not have to clone `x`.  Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Is `usize` a stand-in for some other type, or in you actual code, can you just accept a value iterator instead of a reference iterator? Then you can use `.copied()` to convert the reference iterators to value ones, as long as your underlying type is copy.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is changing your function signature to `where T: Iterator<Item = usize>` and calling it like `foo(vec.iter().copied())`

Comment: It really is a usize.  Basically, I need to pass indices into a function and have those indices come either from a range or a vector.  I suppose `copied` would work and that's a good idea.  Really, I just need the index location and don't care about ownership of the value, so I'd like something efficient without a lot of typing when calling the function.

Comment: Or [accept anything that can be borrowed as a `usize`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6d5218ebd97ab14258f06d1e6ee1ef53).

Comment: @Shepmaster That fixes my issue.  Thanks!  If you add that as the answer, I'll close this out.

Comment: I suspect Shepmaster will forgive me for marking it as a duplicate.